# Why can't I access a value in an object using a key provided by the object?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to generate an array from an object using Javascript in Google Apps Script so I can write the array to a sheet. I have an object `campers` that contains an object for each person identified by a unique number. When I try to access the person's record, I get undefined. Here's the function:

```
function processData(data){  // Returning from client with full object - parse and write to spreadsheet
  Logger.log(data)
  var campers = data; // All camper data and headers
  var headers = campers.headers; // Array of ordered questions
  var nHeaders = headers.length;
  var array = [];  // Array to build - each row is one camper

  for (uid in campers){ // All objects in campers object
    if (uid!='headers'){ // want campers only
      Logger.log(uid);
      Logger.log(campers[uid]);
      var row = [];
      for (var j=0; j<nHeaders; j++){  // Go through all questions
        if(campers[uid][headers[j]]) row.push(campers[uid][headers[j]]); // Add that value to the array if it exists
        else row.push(null);
      }
      array.push(row);
    }
  }
  var final = ss.getSheetByName('ParseUpload');
  final.getRange("A1").offset(0,0,array.length, nHeaders).setValues(array);
  return; 
}
```

When I run it, I get the following log:

```
[16-08-12 02:07:31:240 PDT] {headers=[Card Number, Unique ID, Last Name, First Name, Email, Status], 123456={Status=Non-Attend, Unique ID=123456, Email=test3@test.edu, First Name=John, Card Number=456789012, Last Name=Doe}, 987654={Status=Attend, Unique ID=987654, Email=test2@test.edu, First Name=Jane, Card Number=5, Last Name=Doe}, 1234567={Status=Attend, Unique ID=1234567, Email=test1@test.edu, First Name=John, Card Number=123456789, Last Name=Smith}}
[16-08-12 02:07:31:298 PDT] 123456
[16-08-12 02:07:31:299 PDT] undefined
[16-08-12 02:07:31:300 PDT] 987654
[16-08-12 02:07:31:301 PDT] undefined
[16-08-12 02:07:31:301 PDT] 1234567
[16-08-12 02:07:31:302 PDT] undefined
```

Why is it that the value of `uid`, which is definitely a key in `campers`, returns undefined for `campers[uid]`? I've searched through similar questions and found references to how to access objects using bracket notation, but nothing for getting undefined on something that is defined (I think). Please tell me there's something obvious I'm missing here or direct me to another question if this is indeed a duplicate.

Here's the structure of `data`:

```
{
    "headers": ["Card Number", "Unique ID", "Last Name", "First Name", "Email", "Status"],
    "123456": {
        "First Name": "John",
        "Unique ID": 123456,
        "Email": "test3#test.edu",
        "Card Number": 456789012,
        "Last Name": "Doe",
        "Status": "Non-Attend"
    },
    "987654": {
        "First Name": "Jane",
        "Unique ID": 987654,
        "Email": "test2@test.edu",
        "Card Number": 5,
        "Last Name": "Doe",
        "Status": "Attend"
    },
    "1234567": {
        "First Name": "John",
        "Unique ID": 1234567,
        "Email": "test1@test.edu",
        "Card Number": 123456789,
        "Last Name": "Smith",
        "Status": "Attend"
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
If I define `campers` directly in the function using the above structure, it works fine:

```
function processData(){ 
    var campers = {
    "headers": ["Card Number", "Unique ID", "Last Name", "First Name", "Email", "Status"],
    "123456": {
        "First Name": "John",
        "Unique ID": 123456,
        "Email": "test3@test.edu",
        "Card Number": 456789012,
        "Last Name": "Doe",
        "Status": "Non-Attend"
    },
    "987654": {
        "First Name": "Jane",
        "Unique ID": 987654,
        "Email": "test2@test.edu",
        "Card Number": 5,
        "Last Name": "Doe",
        "Status": "Attend"
    },
    "1234567": {
        "First Name": "John",
        "Unique ID": 1234567,
        "Email": "test1@test.edu",
        "Card Number": 123456789,
        "Last Name": "Smith",
        "Status": "Attend"
    }
}
  var headers = campers.headers; // Array of ordered questions
  var nHeaders = headers.length;
  var array = [];  // Array to build - each row is one camper

  for (uid in campers){ // All objects in campers object
    if (uid!='headers'){ // want campers only
      Logger.log(uid);
      Logger.log(campers[uid]);
      var row = [];
      for (var j=0; j<nHeaders; j++){  // Go through all questions
        if(campers[uid][headers[j]]) row.push(campers[uid][headers[j]]); // Add that value to the array if it exists
        else row.push(null);
      }
      array.push(row);
    }

  }
  Logger.log(array);
  //var final = ss.getSheetByName('ParseUpload');
  //final.getRange("A1").offset(0,0,array.length, nHeaders).setValues(array);
  return; 
}
```

Does this help? Maybe someone can see why a locally defined `campers` works but it doesn't work when passed in as `data`.

**EDIT 2**
I tried some additional logging, without changing the rest of the function:

```
var keys = Object.keys(campers);
Logger.log(keys)
for (var uid in campers){ // All objects in campers object

  if (uid!='headers'){ // want campers only
    Logger.log(uid);
    Logger.log(keys.indexOf(uid));
    Logger.log(campers[uid]);
    Logger.log(campers[keys[0]]);
    Logger.log(campers[Object.keys(campers)[0]]);
    Logger.log(campers[123456]);
    Logger.log(campers['123456']);
    var row = [];
    for (var j=0; j<nHeaders; j++){  // Go through all questions
      if(campers[uid][headers[j]]) row.push(campers[uid][headers[j]]); // Add that value to the array if it exists
      else row.push(null);
    }
    array.push(row);
  }
}
```

Here's the resulting log:

```
[16-08-12 07:37:57:069 EDT] [123456, 987654, 1234567, headers]
[16-08-12 07:37:57:070 EDT] 123456
[16-08-12 07:37:57:072 EDT] 0.0
[16-08-12 07:37:57:073 EDT] undefined
[16-08-12 07:37:57:074 EDT] undefined
[16-08-12 07:37:57:075 EDT] undefined
[16-08-12 07:37:57:075 EDT] undefined
[16-08-12 07:37:57:076 EDT] undefined
```

So `uid` is found in the list of keys, but it seems like the values are somehow inaccessible. UGH!

Comment: I see your `uid` is a global variable. Does any other function modify `uid`?

Comment: @melpomene: Even if it did, there's no opportunity for that function to run between `Logger.log(uid);` and `Logger.log(campers[uid]);`

Comment: @ Tiffany: What does `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(data))` log?

Comment: @TiffanyG.Wilson: Good deal. I've edited that into the question for you (I formatted the value usint http://jsonlint.com for readability).

Comment: What happens if you declare `uid` as a local variable? `for (var uid in campers)`

Comment: @melpomene and @barmar, defining `var uid` locally makes no difference.

Comment: @TiffanyG.Wilson: Fundamentally, other than a typo (you have `i<nHeaders` where you wanted `j<nHeaders`), that works: https://jsfiddle.net/k2a2kg4u/ So more context is needed for us to help you. Your use of `for-in` is correct, and the string that `uid` will get on each iteration *will* identify a property in the object, and the object you've shown has non-`undefined` values for those properties. The way you're accessing them (`campers[uid]`) is correct. So something unusual is going on.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I fixed the typo, thanks for seeing that. I am building the `campers` object client-side through the Google Apps Script HTML Service. I can log and access the object as expected in the script within the HTML file. I was thinking the problem had something to do with strings vs numbers for the `uid` key, but that didn't go anywhere. What additional information should I provide?

Comment: @TiffanyG.Wilson: Sadly, I don't know. :-| That should be working. You're right the string vs. number thing isn't a thing (they're strings by the time they're object property keys).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I tried defining `campers` directly in the function (see edit) and it works. Any reason why the object passed in as a parameter wouldn't work while the locally-defined one does?

Comment: @TiffanyG.Wilson: Nope, none at all. The only possibility that comes to mind is if the object that you're passing in is not a standard JavaScript object. My only suggestion (it's a bit of a shot in the dark) is to try using `campers[+uid]` rather than `campers[uid]`. That's completely pointless with a real JavaScript object (and really, it shouldn't work if the JavaScript engine is per spec), but...maybe worth a dry.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Nope, didn't work. Time to step away for a few hours and see if a lightbulb goes off.

Comment: How are you sending data object to google app script? are you sending it thorough `google.script.run` api?

Comment: @MShoaib91: yes, through `google.script.run`. I found a fix (see my answer) but I still don't know why it didn't work in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know what caused the problem, but I found a fix. Thanks to TJ.Crowder's comments asking me to show the `JSON.stringify(data)` result and wondering if the object is not a standard JavaScript object, I tried the following upon entering the function:

```
var data2 = JSON.stringify(data);
var campers = JSON.parse(data2);
```

For some reason, converting the object to a `JSON` string then immediately back to an object works.